# Inverse of Matrix?

Tags: matrices

What is the inverse of the following matrix ?

[image]

Give a general formula for calculating the such matrix of dimension n-by-n.
Grateful.

Comment: $A^{-1}=(\det A)^{-1}\operatorname{adj}A$. The matrix $\operatorname{adj}A$ is the *adjugate*. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix

Comment: The inverse of a symmetric matrix has no special property, besides being itself symmetric. Use the formulas for general matrices: adjugate matrix or LU decomposition. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition

Answer (score 1):

just read the wikipedia article 
http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Matrix#Verfahren
Unfortunately it's on german and I didn't saw a English version, but the algorithm is not so hard.

Write the matrix down for which you want to compute the inverse and next to this write down the identity matrix $\mathbb{I}$. Then you can just transform your matrix $A$ with elementary row operations into diaginal form and then if every diagonal element is different form $0$ (i.e. $A$ is diaginable), you can transform it further until you get the identity matrix. If you do every operation you did with $A$ to the identity matrix, at the end you obtain the inverse

a small example

$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$

$\left(\begin{array}{cc|cc} 1 & 2 \, & \, 1 & 0 \\ {\color{BrickRed} 2} & 3 \, & \, 0 & 1\end{array}\right) \rightarrow \left(\begin{array}{cc|cc} 1 & {\color{OliveGreen} 2} \, & \, 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \, & \, -2 & 1\end{array}\right) \rightarrow \left(\begin{array}{cc|cc} 1 & 0 \, & \, -3 & 2 \\ 0 & {\color{Blue} -1} \, & \, -2 & 1\end{array}\right) \rightarrow \left(\begin{array}{cc|cc} 1 & 0 \, & \, -3 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \, & \, 2 & -1\end{array}\right)$

Comment: @JessicaK, sorry, I inserted the wrong link, no it should be correct

Comment: It's Gauss-Jordan. Here it is the English page of wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination where in 3.2 deals with the inverse of a matrix

Answer (score -2):

In general:

Let A = the above matrix. Try to solve Y in A.Y=X.
Where Y=(y1,y2,y3,y4) and X=(x1,x2,x3,x4)
You will get something like:

ay1 + by2 + cy3 + dy4 = x1

by1 + ey2 + fy3 + gy4 = x2

cy1 + fy2 + hy3 + iy4 = x3

dy1 + gy2 + iy3 + jy4 = x4

Then try to simplify the system to get y1,y2,y3,y4